# Python site-package imports submodule from script root directory

Tags: python, import

I used to have this litte script `main.py` in a directory `eden/` (stripped down to MVE, of course):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# main.py
import pymongo
uri = "***"
mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
```

With a venv virtual environment (homebrew Python 3.9.6, pip 21.3.1, pymongo 3.12.1) it ran like a (py)charm. `eden/` is first in the `sys.path`, else only Python standard lib and the `site-packages` from the `venv`, which just has `pymongo` in the `requirements.txt`.

But now I have placed a little subdirectory next to `main.py` like so for some completely other reason:

```
eden/
  +- monotonic/
  |    +- monotonic.py
  +- main.py
```

No `__init__.py` files anywhere.

With this in place `main.py` fails like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "****/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/server_description.py", line 72, in __init__
    self._last_update_time = _time()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

`_time` comes into `pymongo/server_description.py` like so:

```py
# pymongo/server_description.py
from pymongo.monotonic import time as _time
```

The PyCharm debugger reveals that `_time` is

```
<module 'monotonic.monotonic' from '****/eden/monotonic/monotonic.py'>
```

so the fix is easy (rename `monotonic/` subdirectory), but I completely fail to understand what caused this import:

- How can "my" `monotonic/monotonic.py` match a `from pymongo.monotonic` at all?
- "My" `monotonic/monotonic.py` does not even offer `time` for import (in fact, it's an empty file in the MVE). So why won't the import in `pymongo/server_description.py` fail in the first place?
- Now Python does not `import time as _time` from "my" `monotonic/monotonic.py` but the whole module ends up as `_time`. I cannot even state a proper question here so confused am I.
- The bad import will happen **only** with `monotonic/monotonic.py` in place. When the subdirectory or the `.py` file is named differently, like `tonic/monotonic.py` or `monotonic/tonic.py`, or when `monotonic.py` is placed right next to `main.py` it will not be used. What makes `<x>/<x>.py` special here? Even more so, as no `__init.py__` is involved in `eden/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont put a `__init__.py` file then the folder is considered a namespace package. Thats used to gather different folders in a same package. So when python see that, `monotonic` is considered a namespace package and its content to be gathered together with any other monotonic folder found in path.

At any case I dont understand how time is confused with monotonic.

The solution is to put an empty `__init__.py` file

Comment: Adding an `__init__.py` to the `monotonic/` directory does not change the Exception raised and `_time` actually is still "my" `monotonic/monotonic.py` down in `pymongo/server_description.py`.